# Amazon Alexa Invalid Category

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have been creating Amazon Alexa skills for some time. However, I made some changes to a previous skill and now I keep getting an error when **Building the model**, note that I **Save the model** without any errors.

When I build I have an error:

```
Save Failed
  Invalid category. Error code: - [here is timestamp]
```

Does anyone know what this is supposed to mean? I searched with no results.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error:

```
Invalid category. Error code: SkillManifestError
```

It turns out that you need to go to the "Launch" tab and select a category for your skill and save your settings. You can then skip back to the "Build" tab and build the model.